# How to remove the same and rare words in dataframe pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, text-analysis

How do I remove the same words in the dataframe named df3?
My below codes doesn't seemed to work...

```
 df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.array(c3), columns=["content"]).drop_duplicates()

 def text_processing_cat3(df3):
''=== Removal of common words ==='''
    freq = pd.Series(' '.join(df3['content']).split()).value_counts()[:10]
    freq = list(freq.index)
    df3['content'] = df3['content'].apply(lambda x: " ".join(x for x in 
    x.split() if x not in freq))

'''=== Removal of rare words ==='''
freq = pd.Series(' '.join(df3['content']).split()).value_counts()[-10:]
freq = list(freq.index)
df3['content'] = df3['content'].apply(lambda x: " ".join(x for x in 
x.split() if x not in freq))


 return df3

  print(text_processing_cat3(df3)
```

The sample output for the above is:

```
 cat_id                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           content
0      3  male malay man nkda walking stick home ambulant ws void deck able walk bendemeer mall home bus stop away adli stays daughter family husband none image image image order cancellation note ct brain duplicate image
1      3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      yo chinese man nkda phx hypertension hyperlipidemia benign hyperplasia open cholecystectomy gallbladder empyema distal gastrectomy pud penetrating aortic
```

Please help check the codes and improve the codes above. Thank you!!

Comment: Can you add some data sample and expected output - 5 rows?

Comment: @jezrael I did not add data sample as it is very huge..

Comment: If `c3 = ['a a s','d d f','f d s f d']` what is expected output ?

Comment: Because if need remove top 10 words your soluion working nice, test with top 2 `freq = pd.Series(' '.join(df3['content']).split()).value_counts()[:2].index`

Comment: @jezrael I have already provided the sample output. Please take a look!

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: @jezrael I have updated my codes already please take a look (if u look at the first sentence, it has the same word - image

Comment: Problem is I have no input data, so cannot compare with ouput. So not understand what need.

Comment: Always the best is working with samm data sample like `c3 = ['male male malay','stick stick void','void stick malay void stick']
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.array(c3), columns=["content"]).drop_duplicates()` and get expected output. You can easy verify if solution working. then apply code to real data.